# Is there a way to hide bones that don't have vertex groups

Tags: armature, bones, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I need to hide bones that don't have any associated vertex groups, so I can select the bones that only have weight painted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weight is a property of vertex groups, so you can't have an automatic procedure to select and hide bones with or without weight. Anyway you can manually move all unwanted bones in a separate bone layer (M in pose mode), and make this layer visible or invisible.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That solution is a good one. But not a automatic procedure (as you said). But I will try your solution .